# jQuery rendering aberrations between Chrome & Safari

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, safari, webkit, rendering

This [site](http://www.star-telegram.com/dfwvarsity/) was developed in early 2010 (based on the developer's use of jQuery version 1.4.1). Around two months ago , users noticed a recurring break in the top navigation and search menu while using Chrome. It worked (and still works) in Safari and Firefox.

It doesn't appear that there is any browser-specific code except for IE bug fixes. As both Chrome and Safari are built on Webkit, I would have assumed that they would display the same. So, deprecated elements, Webkit-specific code, maybe it's something not even related to jQuery? Ghosts possibly? I'm stumped.

I'm working in Chrome Version 23.0.1271.95 - I'm sure the people who initially noticed it were using older versions.

Comment: What happens when you upgrade to the latest versions of jQuery (1.8.3) and jQuery-UI (1.9.2)?

Comment: Make a copy of the page and remove things until you are left with a small test-case that we can use to recreate your issue. Chances are you will find the problem on the way.